# OOP: To create a utils class or extend a common base object?

Tags: java, oop

I've got a bunch of related classes, they all implement a certain interface to do the same function in different ways.

About 70% of the code in any one class is unique, and about 30% can be re-used between 2 or more classes. There are about 30 such classes in the set.

I just can't decide what's more logical:

> Create a big base class with all the reusable functions in it, or just create a utils class with the common functions in it.

The two approaches appear the same to me, but is there a reason I might favor one over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The answer is dependent on the nature of your methods.** `Util` classes/methods are more useful when you want to perform some operation on **stateless object values(independent)** e.g. `getMaxOfArray(int[] array)`. To re-iterate, when you pass certain(limited) arguments to a method and get the expected output from the method then you may consider making that method as `Util` class method. This is the reason, normally util methods are created as `static` and are not associated with class instances.

If this is the behavior then use the `Util` class. But if your methods are heavily dependent on object instances then better to use Class Hierarchy with common methods defined in the base class.

Answer (score 1):

The relationship between a parent class and its child should be quite special, the child "is a" more specialized case of the parent. Would your common functionality fit into this kind of thinking? When you talk about a "big base class", I suspect not, but given the information you've supplied that's just a hunch.

If the helper functionality doesn't fit into this kind of relationship, then I would suggest utility classes.

Bear in mind though it may also be appropriate to mix and match, it all depends on what each method is doing.

Comment: Your hunch is right, the core functionality is the implementation of one primary method defined by the interface mentioned. The common functionality are functions, and ways of representing data. However due to the nature of the code there *are* some places where I am re-using objects such as a large StringBuffer in those functions, which I don't want to recreate each time, this is not easy to encapsulate in a utility class. So I think you're point about mix and match is well said.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to identify classes with common functionality, Group them and extract an interface out.

Best example to look @ is the way Java Collections have been managed.

You can have
 1. Interface Hierarchy
 2. Abstract classes shared between common Concrete classes 
 3. Utility classes

Answer (score 0):

if there is some functionality that can be used independently as a utility, I'd prefer a util class as it is easy to test and can be used wherever required with no side effect, rather than going in heirarchy or composition unless it logically makes sense

Comment: plus it opens up the possibility of it being reused elsewhere, since it is an atom